# Zend framework 2.3.1 file upload: error: temporary file could not be renamed

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2, lampp

I am in lampp environment. All files and directories in /lampp have write permissions. The form upload correctly the temporary file, but I can't move it in another directory because of this error...I am using this method in the action of my controller (I followed official tutorial):

```
$request = new \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request();
$files   = $request->getFiles();
$filter = new \Zend\Filter\File\RenameUpload(array(
                              'overwrite'            => true,
                              'use_upload_name'      => true,
                              'use_upload_extension' => true,
                              'target'               => '/public/img/'
                              ));
echo $filter->filter($files['fileupload']);

return $this->redirect()->toRoute('location');
```

Any idea??

Answer (score 1):

I resolved by myself...it was impossible to rewrite the file because there was a syntax error in the code I wrote above. Instead of:

```
'target'               => '/public/img/'
```

I have to write:

```
'target'               => 'public/img'
```

Now the temporary file is correctly renamed and moved in the setted directory :)